# How do I use absolute URLs?

Tags: views, 8, uri, emails

I created a view for node titles only. I have inserted this view in simplenews newsletter using the *Insert view* module. The node title in newsletter emails are relative and broken. How do I configure my view so that absolute URls are used?

> [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. Add `Content: Link to Content` field to your View** . Your view fields will look as shown below.

[image]

---

**2. Make sure that your Title field is outputted as plain text.** In the `Content:Title` field settings uncheck the checkbox "Link to the Content". This is done because you'll use plain title text as a token for the link text. `Exclude Title field from display`, as it will be displayed later as an absolute link text.

[image]

---

**3. Create settings for the absolute link output in `Content: Link to Content` field settings.**

Open REWRITE RESULTS fieldset in `Content: Link to Content` field settings and check the following boxes:

**✓** Override the output of this field with custom text (set `{{ title }}` as text)
**✓** Output this field as a custom link
**✓** Use absolute path

[image]